# Splitting of Power between Judges and Kings

Tags: halacha, malchut-royalty, melachim-kings-book-of, shoftim--book-of

In Dvarim 16, G-d orders the Judges to judge the nation. In the next chapter the concept of a Jewish King is introduced.

It seems like the Torah supports splitting of powers.

On the other hand,from the Tanach it seems that its either Judges or Kings. When Kingship was introduced, the Kings (as evident from the story with Shlomo and the two woman) is also the judge.

In the second temple period it seems like the idea of Power splitting is reintroduced. The Sanhedrin and the King of Judea existed next to each other.

What is the correct understanding?

Comment: I've read somewhere that Dovid HaMelech would consult the Sanhedrin when waging war(s).

Comment: Its in Brachot Daf 3 or 4. But here its more about the right to judge,Not political desiscipns.